# Hover effect : expand bottom border

Tags: css, border, css-transitions, css-transforms

I'm trying to get a **transition hover effect on border** that the border expands on hover.

```css
h1 {
  color: #666;
}

h1:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  content: '';
  height: 40px;
  width: 275px;
  border-bottom: solid 3px #019fb6;
  transition: left 250ms ease-in-out, right 250ms ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
}

h1:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<h1>CSS IS AWESOME</h1>
```

I've tried this on [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mfn5nefb/)

Answer (score 285, accepted):

To **expand the bottom border on hover**, you can use `transform:scaleX();` ([mdn reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale)) and transition it from 0 to 1 on the hover state.

Here is an example of what the border hover effect can look like :
[image: Expand border hover effect]

The border and transition are set on a **pseudo element** to prevent transitioning the text and avoid adding markup.
To expand the bottom border from left or right, you can change the [transform-origin property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) to the left or right of the pseudo element:

```css
h1 { color: #666;display:inline-block; margin:0;text-transform:uppercase; }
h1:after {
  display:block;
  content: '';
  border-bottom: solid 3px #019fb6;  
  transform: scaleX(0);  
  transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
}
h1:hover:after { transform: scaleX(1); }
h1.fromRight:after{ transform-origin:100% 50%; }
h1.fromLeft:after{  transform-origin:  0% 50%; }
```

```html
<h1 class="fromCenter">Expand from center</h1><br/>
<h1 class="fromRight">Expand from right</h1><br/>
<h1 class="fromLeft">Expand from left</h1>
```

### Expand bottom border on hover with 2 lines

You can achieve this effect when the text spans on 2 lines. The before pseudo element is absolutely positioned to make underline of the first line with `bottom:1.2em;`:

```css
h1 { position:relative;color: #666;display:inline-block; margin:0;text-transform:uppercase;text-align:center;line-height:1.2em; }
h1:after, h1:before {
  display:block;
  content: '';
  border-bottom: solid 3px #019fb6;  
  transform: scaleX(0);  
  transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
}
h1:before{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:1.2em; left:0;
  width:100%;
}
.ef2:hover:after {
  transition-delay:150ms;
}
  
h1:hover:after, h1:hover:before { transform: scaleX(1); }
```

```html
<h1>Expand border<br/>on two lines</h1>
<br/>
<br/>
<h1 class="ef2">Expand border<br/>effect two</h1>
```

### Different transition direction on hover in and out :

The point is to change the transform-origin position from one side to the other on the hover state. This way the bottom boder **enters from one side on hover and exits on the other** when the element isn't hovered anymore.
Here is a demo :

```css
h1 { color: #666;display:inline-block; margin:0;text-transform:uppercase; }
h1:after {
  display:block;
  content: '';
  border-bottom: solid 3px #019fb6;  
  transform: scaleX(0);  
  transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
}
h1.fromLeft:after{ transform-origin: 100% 50%; }
h1.fromRight:after{  transform-origin:   0% 50%; }
h1.fromLeft:hover:after{ transform: scaleX(1); transform-origin:   0% 50%; }
h1.fromRight:hover:after{ transform: scaleX(1); transform-origin: 100% 50%; }
```

```html
<h1 class="fromRight">Expand from right</h1><br/>
<h1 class="fromLeft">Expand from left</h1>
```

Comment: With `scaleX(0.0001)` I'm getting some artifacts but setting it to `scaleX(0)` seems to solve this.

Comment: @ChristiaanMaks you are right. I am updating the answer

Comment: Is there anyway to do this if the sentences span multiple lines?

Comment: @Philip you can achieve this effect when te text has 2 lines (see my edit in this answer).

Comment: What if you have <span>This is a sentence that spans one line.</span><span>This is a sentence that spans two lines but starts on the first line</span>

Comment: how to implement  in menu dropdown?

Comment: @LidyMonteiro it depends on your markup and context. I can't answer with such little information, sorry.

Comment: How can you do on inputs? Doesn't seem to work. http://jsfiddle.net/vxm3b4fe/ (Also if possible, instead of hover I would like to do `:focus`)

Comment: @JBis unfortunatly inputs don't support pseudo elements so this technique can't be use to underline inputs

Comment: @web-tiki That's unfortunate :(. Thanks for the quick reply. +1 anyway :)

Comment: @JBis you could do something similar though like this  : http://jsfiddle.net/vxm3b4fe/1/ click in the name input.

Comment: @web-tiki Perfect! Thanks. Just don't use a *pseudo* element, instead use a real one.

Comment: @web-tiki Maybe add that as an option in the answer. Same example, just without a pseudo element :)

Comment: @JBis I would rather keep the answer simple as it is now. It works for the vast majority of use cases.

Comment: I'm trying to use this on the bottom of a div, but it's positioning the line separately from the div and making it shorter than the width of the div. How do I control the layout so that it maintains the same length, position as a standard bottom-border style?

Comment: @AlexBanman can you please show me your code ? The description you are making of your issue won't allow me to understand what is going wrong.

Answer (score 19):

We can do this with only `background`. No pseudo-element needed. This is more flexible.

```css
h1 {
  /* you can change these variables to control the border */
  --border-color: purple;
  --border-width: 5px;
  --bottom-distance: 0px; /* you can increase this */
  
  color: #666;
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: linear-gradient(var(--border-color), var(--border-color));
  background-size: 0% var(--border-width);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transition: background-size 0.3s;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.fromCenter {
  background-position: 50% calc(100% - var(--bottom-distance));
}

.fromRight {
  background-position: 100% calc(100% - var(--bottom-distance));
}

.fromLeft {
  background-position: 0 calc(100% - var(--bottom-distance))
}

h1:hover {
  background-size: 100% var(--border-width);
}
```

```html
<h1 class="fromCenter">Expand from center</h1><br/>
<h1 class="fromRight">Expand from right</h1><br/>
<h1 class="fromLeft">Expand from left</h1>
```

[image]

Multiple line animation:

```css
h1 {
  /* you can change these variables to control the border */
  --border-color: purple;
  --border-width: 5px;
  --bottom-distance: 0px; /* you can increase this */
  
  color: #666;
  display: inline; /* should be 'inline' for multiple line animation */
  background-image: linear-gradient(var(--border-color), var(--border-color));
  background-size: 0% var(--border-width);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transition: background-size 0.5s;
}

.fromCenter {
  background-position: 50% calc(100% - var(--bottom-distance));
}

.fromRight {
  background-position: 100% calc(100% - var(--bottom-distance));
}

.fromLeft {
  background-position: 0 calc(100% - var(--bottom-distance))
}

h1:hover {
  background-size: 100% var(--border-width);
}
```

```html
<h1 class="fromLeft">Expand from <br>left with <br>multiple line</h1>
```

[image]

Answer (score 15):

simple and lightweight version

```css
li {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.cool-link {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.cool-link::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 2px;
    background: #000;
    transition: width .3s;
}

.cool-link:hover::after {
    width: 100%;
    //transition: width .3s;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a class="cool-link" href="#">A cool link</a></li>
    <li><a class="cool-link" href="#">A cool link</a></li>
    <li><a class="cool-link" href="#">A cool link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks! The accepted answer didn't work for me, but this did. If anyone else is having issues give this a try.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old post and it is already answered but you might like the following effect too.

```
<div class="cd-single-point">
    <a class="cd-img-replace" href="#0"></a>
</div>

   .cd-single-point {
    position: absolute;
    list-style-type: none;
    left: 20px;
    top: 20px;
  }

  .cd-single-point>a {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 2;
      display: block;
      width: 10px;
      height: 10px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background: #0079ff;
      -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s;
      -moz-transition: background-color 0.2s;
      -o-transition: background-color 0.2s;
      transition: background-color 0.2s;
  }

  .cd-single-point::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    animation: cd-pulse 2s infinite;
  }

  @keyframes cd-pulse
  {
  0%  {box-shadow:0 0 0 0 #0079ff}
  100%{box-shadow:0 0 0 20px rgba(255,150,44,0)}
  }
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/yeghb8oo/)

Answer (score 6):

```css
h1 {
  color: #666;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0;
  text-transform:uppercase;
 }
h1:after {
  display:block;
  content: '';
  border-bottom: solid 3px #92a8d1;  
  transform: scaleX(0);  
  transition: transform 800ms ease-in-out;
}
h1:hover:after {
 transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<h1 class="fromCenter">Hover Over Me</h1><br/>
```

Answer (score 4):

```css
h1 {
  /* you can change these variables to control the border */
  --border-color: purple;
  --border-width: 5px;
  --bottom-distance: 0px; /* you can increase this */
  
  color: #666;
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: linear-gradient(var(--border-color), var(--border-color));
  background-size: 0% var(--border-width);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transition: background-size 0.3s;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.fromCenter {
  background-position: 50% calc(100% - var(--bottom-distance));
}

.fromRight {
  background-position: 100% calc(100% - var(--bottom-distance));
}

.fromLeft {
  background-position: 0 calc(100% - var(--bottom-distance))
}

h1:hover {
  background-size: 100% var(--border-width);
}
```

```html
<h1 class="fromCenter">Expand from center</h1><br/>
<h1 class="fromRight">Expand from right</h1><br/>
<h1 class="fromLeft">Expand from left</h1>
```

Answer (score 3):

we can do using simple transition effect.

HTML

```
<h1>CSS IS AWESOME</h1>
```

CSS

```
h1 {
    color: #666;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

h1:after {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    content: '';
    height: 40px;
    height: 5px;
    background: #f00;
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
    width: 0;
    bottom: 0;  
}

h1:hover:after {
    width: 270px;
    margin-left: -135px;
}
```

Link to [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mfn5nefb/6/)

Answer (score 1):

```
transition: all 1000ms ease-in-out;
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mfn5nefb/2/)**

or are you looking for this

**[Demo2](http://jsfiddle.net/mfn5nefb/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

```css
h1 {
  color: #666;
}

h1:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  content: '';
  height: 40px;
  width: 275px;
  border-bottom: solid 3px #019fb6;
  transition: all 550ms ease-in-out;
  border-bottom-width: 0px;
}

h1:hover:after {
  border-bottom-width: 5px;
}
```

```html
<h1>CSS IS AWESOME</h1>
```