# How to animate border transition expand with CSS?

Tags: html, css, border

I'm trying to create a CSS transition where the `border-bottom` of `a href` element expands on `:hover` to the width of the link.

What I could find is a CSS solution where the `background width` is animated:
http://jsfiddle.net/mfn5nefb/82/

But that's not what I want, because after click on a navigation tab I want to leave the border as is. So I'd have to directly animate the border, instead of the background.

```
<!-- assume the border-bottom is only applied to an active=clicked navigation tab -->
<h1 style="border-bottom: 3px solid green;">CSS IS AWESOME</h1>

h1 {
    color: #666;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

h1:after {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    content: '';
    height: 40px;
    height: 5px;
    background: #f00;
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
    width: 0;
    bottom: 0;  
}

h1:hover:after {
    width: 270px;
    margin-left: -135px;
}
```

Here you see the "active" link gets a green border. And on hover I'd like to animate the other tabs, but the border itself. Currently the background is animated, which appears *above* the border and thus looks misaligned.

Comment: Related to [Expand bottom border from center on hover](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28623446/expand-bottom-border-from-center-on-hover)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can still achieve this by using a pseudo-element (with `background`) and expand it on `hover`. All that is required is to set the value for the `bottom` property as the inverse of expected `border-width`  and also set the `height` of the pseudo-element to be the same as the `border-width`.

```css
h1 {
  color: #666;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
h1:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  content: '';
  height: 3px;
  background: #f00;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
  width: 0;
  bottom: -3px;
}
h1:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!-- assume the border-bottom is only applied to an active=clicked navigation tab -->
<h1 style="border-bottom: 3px solid green;">Tab1</h1>
<h1>Tab2</h1>
```

---

Another way to achieve the same effect using the `border` property itself would be to use `transform: scale` like in the below snippet. Here the `scaleX(0)` makes the original width of the element as 0 and on `hover` it is transitioned to full width using `scaleX(1)`. Since, default `transform-origin` is at `50%` in X-axis, the border looks as though it is expanding from the center.

```css
h1 {
  color: #666;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
h1:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  top: 0%;
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
  transform: scaleX(0);
}
h1:hover:after {
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<!-- assume the border-bottom is only applied to an active=clicked navigation tab -->
<h1 style="border-bottom: 3px solid green;">Tab1</h1>
<h1>Tab2</h1>
```