# Grow CSS from center to a fixed width

Tags: html, css, animation

I have the below hover effect which works well. However, I am trying to add a fixed width of the blue line. For example a max-width of 100px. When I try to amend the code below the animation breaks and doesn't grow from the center.

Any ideas on how to fix the code below so it animates from the center to a fixed width?

```css
body {
  width:100%;
}

div {
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  top:45%;
  left:50%;
  border-bottom:4px solid blue;
  width:0%;
  text-align:center;
  animation: line 2s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes line {
  from {
    left:50%;
    width:0%;
  }
  to {
    left:5%;
    width:90%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>Heading</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the [:after pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) instead of adding the border to the actual element. I also reduced your animation time because it seemed a little long:

```css
body {
  width:100%;
}

div {
  display:inline-block;
  position:absolute;
  top:45%;
  left:50%;
  text-align:center;
}
  div:hover:after {
    content:"";
    display:block;
    width:0;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:4px;
    background:blue;
    animation:line .5s linear forwards;
  }

@keyframes line {
  from {
    width:0%;
  }
  to {
    width:100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>Heading</div>
```

You can also do this without `keyframes` like this:

```css
body {
  width:100%;
}

div {
  display:inline-block;
  position:absolute;
  top:45%;
  left:50%;
  text-align:center;
}
  div:after {
    content:"";
    display:block;
    height:4px;
    background:blue;
    width:0;
    margin:0 auto;
    transition:.5s all;
  }
  div:hover:after {
    width:100%;
  }
```

```html
<div>Heading</div>
```

Comment: A similar answer could be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35066584/how-to-animate-border-transition-expand-with-css

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution 1

Just add an additional `span` element for which you can limit the width:

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
}

div {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 0%;
  animation: line 2s linear forwards;
}

.heading {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 200px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid blue;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

@keyframes line {
  from {
    left: 50%;
    width: 0%;
  }
  to {
    left: 5%;
    width: 90%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div><span class="heading">Heading</span></div>
```

#### Solution 2

Don't use absolute positioning to center your `div`:

```css
div {
  display: block;
  width: 0%;
  animation: line 2s linear forwards;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 200px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid blue;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

@keyframes line {
  from {
    width: 0%;
  }
  to {
    width: 90%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>Heading</div>
```