# Expand bottom border on hover in React.js using Material ui library

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, animation, material-ui

My question is like this question,
[Hover effect : expand bottom border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28623446/hover-effect-expand-bottom-border)

how can i achieve the same effect in React using makeStyles of Material ui. I am trying like this

```
const useSTyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
 //other code
  remove: {
    textTransform: "none",
    fontSize: "0.75rem",
    "&:after": {
      transition: theme.transitions.create(["transform"], {
        duration: theme.transitions.duration.standard,
      }),
      transform: "scale(0)",
      borderBottom: "1px solid #dbdada",
      transformOrigin: "0% 50%",
    },
    "&:hover": {
      background: "none",
      "&:after": {
        transform: "scale(1)",
      },
    },
  },

 // other code
}));
```

This is the component on which i am trying to create border bottom animation:

```
  <Button
      classes={{root:classes.remove}}
      onClick={() => handleClickRemove(item)}
    >
      Remove
    </Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

To animate `Button` bottom border in `Material-ui` you could create a `transition` for `border-bottom`. Then inject css into Button `root` class using `classes` prop.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-button-forked-q49wb?file=/src/index.js) a working example.

Basically, in Button `classes` prop, inject `remove` css into root like:

```
<Button
    variant="contained"
    classes={{
      root: classes.remove
    }}
  >
    Remove
  </Button>
```

Then on `useStyles`:

```
 const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
 ...
  remove: {
    textTransform: "none",
    fontSize: "0.75rem",
    borderBottom: "2px solid transparent",
    transition: theme.transitions.create(["border-bottom"], {
      duration: 1000
    }),
    "&:hover": {
       textDecoration: "none",
       borderBottom: "2px solid black"
    }
  }
 ...
}));
```

Note: when you create the transition for `border-bottom` you could change the `easing` like the `duration` (at default, easing is `easeInOut`).

Comment: i want animation in which border can be seen coming from left to write. i have attached the link to a previous stack overflow question, that question was without react though. i need exactly that animation.