# Css pseudo-class 'after' not working with tailwindcss

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm trying to recreate [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28623446/hover-effect-expand-bottom-border) with tailwindcss however when I implement this the hover effect is not working.

```js
export default Home(){
    return(
        <a
            href={item.href}
            className="px-3 py-2 text-sm font-medium after:origin-center after:scale-x-0 after:border-b-2 after:transition-all after:duration-500 after:ease-in-out after:content-none hover:after:scale-x-100 hover:after:border-white"
            aria-current="current item"
        >
           Item name
        </a>
    )
}
```

Comment: Are you using tailwind JIT? Because if not, you might not have the `after` `psuedoclass` enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a working example using Tailwind following your desired result.

You can check the live demo here: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-ogid1p?file=src/App.jsx)

The environment is installed following Tailwind official [guide](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/vite).

Hope this will help!

Example:

```
<div className="flex flex-col gap-6 justify-center items-center">
  <a
    href="#"
    className="inline-block text-4xl text-slate-400 uppercase visited:text-slate-400 hover:text-slate-400 after:block after:origin-center after:scale-x-0 after:border-b-4 after:transition-all after:duration-500 after:ease-in-out hover:after:scale-x-100 hover:after:border-sky-500"
    aria-current="current item"
  >
    Hover effect center
  </a>
  <a
    href="#"
    className="inline-block text-4xl text-slate-400 uppercase visited:text-slate-400 hover:text-slate-400 after:block after:origin-left after:scale-x-0 after:border-b-4 after:transition-all after:duration-500 after:ease-in-out hover:after:scale-x-100 hover:after:border-sky-500"
    aria-current="current item"
  >
    Hover effect left
  </a>
  <a
    href="#"
    className="inline-block text-4xl text-slate-400 uppercase visited:text-slate-400 hover:text-slate-400 after:block after:origin-right after:scale-x-0 after:border-b-4 after:transition-all after:duration-500 after:ease-in-out hover:after:scale-x-100 hover:after:border-sky-500"
    aria-current="current item"
  >
    Hover effect right
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Problem was me using 'after:content-none'